# how to count all Operators and Operands in java class file

Tags: java

how to count all Operators and Operands in java class file? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: A sample code might help. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i just need to calculate Halstead metric, so i need to calculate all Operators and Operands

Comment: @Bragboy - that is bound to fail in obscure cases.

Comment: Halstead and Java - here's a good article about where it makes sense to use Halstead metrics for Java code: [The Halstead Metrics](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar2.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Doing this kind of thing using regexes is unreliable.  The syntax of Java is sufficiently complex that there are bound to be tricky corner cases that will cause your regexes to miscount.

Similarly using a bytecode analyser is liable to give you incorrect results because there isn't necessarily a one-to-one correspondence between source code operators / operands and bytecode instructions.  The Java compiler may reorganize and rewrite the code in non-obvious ways.

The best way to do this sort of thing is to find a decent Java AST library, use that to parse your source code, and then traverse the AST to extract the information you need.  (In this case, you need to count the operator and operand nodes.)

Comment: I've used ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org) in the past for walking a Java AST. The Java grammar for it is here: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g

Answer (score 1):

Forget regex (you'll never get that right without getting false positives like operators in comments etc), you're going to have to run a visitor over your code that counts operators. Now you can either use a source code parser or a byte code parser to do that.

For source code parsing I'd suggest the [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) project. There, you'd create a custom Visitor extending [VoidVisitorAdapter](http://javaparser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/JavaParser/src/japa/parser/ast/visitor/VoidVisitorAdapter.java) and overriding several relevant methods like this:

```
public void visit(AssignExpr n, A arg) {
    // track the operator here
    super.visit(n, arg); // resume visitor
}
```

On the byte code side, you'd probably use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and extend [ClassAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter.html) to create your visitor. Both versions should work equally well. Or maybe not, as [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810097/how-to-count-all-operators-and-operands-in-java-class-file/3810155#3810155) writes (the compiler may have added or removed some operations).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to analyze the bytecode of your class using a library like [bcel](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/).

Or use the sourceforge project [lachesis](http://lachesis.sourceforge.net/) (I haven't tried it):

> Lachesis Analysis is a Software Complexity Measurement program for Object-Oriented source code. Analysis for Java source code and Java byte-code only is currently available.