# How to calculate operator / operand statistics for one class in bytecode?

Tags: java, class, operators, bytecode, operands

I want to calculate the total operands, total operators, unique operands and unique operators in a single class, present as bytecode.

The following question is about the same problem, but for source code: [how to count all Operators and Operands in java class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810097/how-to-count-all-operators-and-operands-in-java-class-file)

It's explicitly stated, that the numbers don't have to add up there.

After doing N number of searches over the internet, I am still unable to figure out these statistics from java bytecode.
I came across words like ASM, BCEL, Code Pro but that does solves the purpose.

I found some open source tools for calculating these metrics from source code but could not find open source tool that works on bytecode.

Comment: The link to that question which consist of a single sentence doesn’t really add value to yours. Please, be more specific about what counts as “operator” or “operand” regarding your question.

Comment: The goal here is to calculate halstead metrics from these operands and operator.  What counts as "operator" or "operand"  still an open question?

Comment: The Halstead-Metrik itself doesn’t define operands and operators. If you just want to separate constants/variables and arithmetic/invocations, the task would be as simple as creating a instruction frequency statistic as each byte code instruction can be categorized as operand, operator or neither. Every of the named tools should be capable of creating such a statistic either directly with provided functions or with the supplied example applications.

Comment: Is there a reference available that defines what are operands, operator or neither for each bytecode instructions.

Comment: Look at [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-7.html). It summerizes the byte code instruction set grouping the instructions technically. You can decide yourself how these groups correlate to the semantic categories. Since it is about mapping ten technical groups to three categories, it shouldn’t need long thinking. Note that when you use [ASM’s visitor API](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) most instructions are naturally grouped by the choice of the specific invoked `visit` method…

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to calculate source level operands from the bytecode, because compilation is a lossy process. For example, constant expressions are evaluated at compile time. If you see a 3 in the bytecode, there's no way to know that it wasn't originally a (1 + 1<<129)|0, say.

Comment: Is there reference available that categorised bytecode level mapping for operands and operator. And whatever is not available for example constant expression can be categorised in neither category.